# Does explicit setting of $MYVIMRC imply its execution as private vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

Vim manual says: *"The $MYVIMRC environment variable is set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set and when using VIMINIT."* Does this also mean that setting of $MYVIMRC (e.g. in the system vimrc) causes automatically its execution as private vimrc?

I tried the following in my system vimrc:

```
let $VIMFILES=$HOME."/Programs/Vim"
let $MYVIMRC=$VIMFILES."/vimrc"
```

but it didn't work. I had to add the line

```
let $VIMINIT="source ".$MYVIMRC
```

Of course, this worked. So my question is if I misunderstood the cited sentence from the manual or else what I have to do to make it work *without* the extra line.

Regards,

Johannes

Comment: No idea if this is the correct interpretation, but I always read that line simply to mean that the environment variable isn’t overwritten if it already exists, and that it doesn’t have any effect on the actual loading that takes place.